# Call a funcion after the execution of a onClick has finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following button rendered in a page, where im trying to implement a scrollToTop props

```
<Button style={{ display: step === 1 ? "unset" : "none" }} onClick={this.requestClick} scrollToTop={true}>Next</Button>
```

Now this button looks like the following

```
const Button: React.SFC<IButtonProps> = props => {
  const { icon, children, className, hidden, displayNone, style, subtype, text } = props;
  const socialIcon = getSocialIcon(subtype);
  const iconElement =
    icon || socialIcon ? (
      <Icon icon={socialIcon || icon} className="u-space-right" />
    ) : null;
    
  const onClick = function (props, e) {
    console.log("clicked")
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (typeof props.onClick === "function") {
      props.onClick(e);

    }

  };

  return (
    <SCButton
      className={className}
      style={style}
      onClick={onClick.bind(null, props)}
      hidden={hidden}
      displayNone={displayNone}
      {...props}
    >
      {iconElement} {children ? children : text}
    </SCButton>
  );
};
```

And the onClick function requestClick is

```
requestClick= () => {
    
    const { paramsData } = this.state;
    let formOK = true

    if (paramsData.length > 0) {
      formOK = this.validationValue();
    } else {
      this.validationValue();
      formOK = false
    }


    formOK && this.props.addStep();

  };
```

Now I need to add somehwere this piece of code.

```
 window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
```

This piece of code must be executed if in requestClick()  the conditions formOK && this.props.addStep(); are TRUE.

Point is, The button component is a general component, and I dont want to put the scrollToTop function in every single component that contains that logic.

So im trying to add it in the button component.

To get something like

```
const Button: React.SFC<IButtonProps> = props => {
  const { icon, children, className, hidden, displayNone, style, subtype, text } = props;
  const socialIcon = getSocialIcon(subtype);
  const iconElement =
    icon || socialIcon ? (
      <Icon icon={socialIcon || icon} className="u-space-right" />
    ) : null;
    
  const onClick = function (props, e) {
    console.log("clicked")
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (typeof props.onClick === "function") {
      props.onClick(e);
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }

  };
```

But I have two problems.
First, the onClick function will only be executed if I comment //{...props} in the return of  in the Button component, as follows

```
 <SCButton
      className={className}
      style={style}
      onClick={onClick.bind(null, props)}
      hidden={hidden}
      displayNone={displayNone}
      //{...props}
    >
      {iconElement} {children ? children : text}
    </SCButton>
```

Because otherwise its getting overwritten (i dont really know why). Im not sure if its safe to comment.
Second problem is that if i comment the spread operator props, i leave it as it is, but if the form validation fails `formOK && this.props.addStep();` it will execute the scrollToTop but i only want it to be executed if it doesnt fail.

So I dont know how ta handle this. To get some sort of true callback from the onClick function passed as prop, and based on that execute or not the scrollToTop.

Comment: put {...props} before your onClick.

Comment: secondly, why you have this. all over a function component, you sure your codes working? 3rd, to answer the question, you can use await/async if props.addStep is a async function.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial The button is functional, the rest is in another component which is class one. I will check on the async await suggestion. Putting props before onClick seems to do the trick